# Which place is best for for "sky diving" out of Rome, Paris & Venice?

Tags: paris, rome, outdoor-activities, venice, parachutes-skydiving

I am planning to visit Rome, Paris & Venice for a holiday. One of my want is to do skydiving through an aeroplane.

Can anyone tell me out of these cities, which one provides skydiving ?

Comment: Probably best to ask the scuba diving and bungee jumping as separate questions. For now we'll treat this one as just sky-diving.
In addition, skydiving exists near Paris, Rome AND Venice.  Could you elaborate on what you mean by "best"?  Do you want the most spectacular view, the highest jump, or the cheapest rates, for example?

Comment: Ok, best means safest and through reliable provider.

Comment: Frankly that's hard to measure. Eg in the states there are over [2.5 million jumps a year, and only 20-30 deaths](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080121195428AA1st7K).  In Europe in 2011 there were just 18 fatalities.  They're all pretty darn safe.  Any other criteria?

Comment: Google gives a ton of results with: "[club de parachutisme paris](http://www.google.fr/#q=club+de+parachutisme+paris)". Same with "[club paracadutismo venezia](http://www.google.it/#q=club+paracadutismo+venezia)" and "[club paracadutismo roma](http://www.google.it/#q=club+paracadutismo+roma)".

Comment: OK I'm closing this for now.  Once more defined criteria is given (please see our [faq] - asking for 'best' is clearly stated as really against the goals in there), you can flag to reopen, and we'll be happy to help out.  But just asking for the best in 3 countries is really too vague.  'Best', by definition, is subjective :/